# how to get a text that is in a div id

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

hi im new to this website im trying to get a title in my forum without pasting it again in the forum  < div class="titleBar" >

so bassicaly what i need is that some code that will get what ever is in that div for example

http://desiztv.com/index.php?threads/watch-colors-live-online-for-free.68/

the title is "Watch Colors Live Online For Free"
 i need some code that i will post in the post and it will get the title it self and i can do that with every post pleae help me with it thankx :)

Comment: Hey there @shahbaz... I was just trying to improve your post a little with capitalization and some formatting. Is there any specific reason you didn't like my edits?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply store the text value in a variable to use wherever you want...

```
<div id="mainTitle>Watch Colors Live Online For Free</div>
```

Using jQuery and JavaScript, we initialize a new variable called `title`.

```
var title = '';
```

Now as soon as your text has been inserted into your `#mainTitle` div element, you can retrieve the text content of that div using this -

```
title = $("#mainTitle").text();
```

Your `title` variable is then available for you to use anywhere you want to copy that text -

```
$("#someElement, #anotherElement, #yetAnotherElement").text(title);
```

All three elements -

```
<div id="someElement">Watch Colors Live Online For Free</div>
<div id="anotherElement">Watch Colors Live Online For Free</div>
<div id="yetAnotherElement">Watch Colors Live Online For Free</div>
```

will now contain the same text as the first `#mainTitle` element.

Comment: thankx i will try it can you tell me is that javascript or php ?

Comment: its jQuery (javascript library)

Comment: @sha - That's not really how this site works. We are not here to write peoples code... That said, you need to come with a specific problem so that people can give specific answers. If you are looking for code to copy and paste into your site I don't think you'll find too much of that here.

Comment: @sha This code is written in jQuery and JavaScript. jQuery is written in JavaScript so it's interchangeable *in this case*. I gave this answer in jQuery because of how you tagged your question. You were not specific enough as to exactly how you wanted to do this. As with many things in programming, "there is more than one way to skin a cat". I took a stab at it.

Comment: @sha - Also, did you see my comment on your *question* above?

Comment: oh hey thank you for your replay i didn't knew that i just needed with some help i thought you guyz could help but that code didn't really help me i think becuase i dont know what are the tags before and after it